# If loop stops after only one iteration without condition being met

Tags: loops

I don't understand why this code is not iterating properly?

```
income = 0
expenses = 10
profit = income - expenses
if profit <= 0:
    income += 1
    print(profit)
```

I would expect it to increment the income by one until 10, however it only runs once, outputting:

```
-10
```

Sincere thanks for answering something at the very, very bottom of the food chain.

Comment: You are not using a loop. ‘If’ is a conditional statement. You need to use a loop like ‘for’

Comment: Thanks for the super-fast reply @hungersoft.  I've tried it with a while loop and it just becomes an infinite loop returning '-10'.

Comment: Check the updated code. You are incrementing income variable but using profit for loop condition.

Comment: Thanks.  Incrementing the input variable is what I'm trying to do though.  In the initial condition income = 0 and expenses = 10 so profit is -10.  I want to then increment income by 1 so that the profit calculation becomes 1 - 10 = -9 and so on until the income has been increased to 10 and profit = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use while loop as follows:

```
income = 0
expenses = 10
profit = income - expenses
while (profit <= 0):
    income += 1
    profit = income - expenses
print(income)
```

Comment: Thanks @hungersoft.  I get the same issue as earlier.  This just set sup an infinite loop returning '-10'

Comment: I have updated the code to increment profit variable instead of income variable

Comment: I have updated the code to increment the income variable as well.

Comment: Thanks @hungersoft.  I **only** want to increment Income though.  I'm trying to vary only the income variable so that it increases and as a result of that the profit increases by one.

Comment: You have initialised profit outside the loop so it will not increment inside the loop unless you explicitly do so. Incrementing income will not affect the profit variable in anyway unless you add the statement profit = income - expenses inside the loop. Or increment profit by 1 which is what you want.

Comment: Check the updated code. That might be what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You nailed it @hungersoft.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You print the difference profit which is indeed -10. Add a loop (while, for) to imcrement, if you have to, and then print income outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Mark1104 - I changed it to the code below and it just looped infinitely...
income = 0
expenses = 10
profit = income - expenses
while (profit <= 0):
    income += 1
print(income)

Answer (score 0):

Hi **IF** statement won't loop. It will execute the statements under it when the condition is satisfied.
Use **While**  where it loops until the condition is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed it to a **While** and it runs infinitely returning -10